# Parallax jQuery Javascript CSS Positioning of Element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, css-position

I have some JavaScript which is confusing me.

I want to position the 'copyright' css class (div) at the bottom of the contaioning div - at the bottom of my page.

```
if(thisRatio>=0 && thisRatio<=1){
            $(this).css("background-position", "50% " + (90-thisRatio*400) + "px");
            $(".black-shield", $(this)).css("opacity", Math.min(0.6, Math.max(0,thisRatio*4-1.8)));
            if(thisAbsPos<-660 && thisAbsPos>-1350){
                $(".copyright", $(this))
                    .css("margin-top", 800 + (-660 - thisAbsPos))
                    .css("margin-bottom", 600 - (-660 - thisAbsPos));
            }else if(thisAbsPos<=-1350){

                $(".copyright", $(this))
                    .css("margin-top", 800 + (-660 +1350))
                    .css("margin-bottom", 600 - (-660 +1350));            
            }else if(thisAbsPos>=-660){

            }
        }
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: If i understand your request, you would like to position a copyright DIV at the bottom of your page, if yes, you can do this without jQuery but with CSS like "Sticky footer" : http://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/sticky-footer/

Comment: this may give you a better idea of what I am trying to achieve - http://rmg-dev.fastnetstaging.co.uk - I am nearly there, but I have a jump on the copyright div, when slowly scrolling down

Comment: What is the problem? What is `this`, `thisRatio`, `thisAbsPos` etc.? What is that code supposed to do?  How does the HTML look like? What do the other styles applied to `.copyright´ look like? What about the other CSS? A random code snippet without context, is like taking a wheel to the garage and saying that your car doesn't work.